# Multiple part form - update database each submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, client-server

I'm sure this isn't the hardest issue to overcome, but I have a lack of understanding on how to handle this particular situation.

Learning MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node to create a web application for learning purposes.

I have a 2 stage submission form.

**Step 1:** Pet info is collected. text based input (pet name, pet description... ). 
Submission of this info goes through my client side controller. Processed and saved to mongo as a new entry.

**Step 2:** Using ng-show/ng-hide, the first form is hidden and a second input form is shown for submitting an image.

Step 2 upload doesn't use a client side controller. Instead I make a direct method=post call to my express route. Multer module is called as middleware to upload my picture to a server side directory and generate JSON image info.

All I want to do is follow up with an update to mongoDB to insert the multer image_path into my previous mongodb collection, so that I can later render the image directly from the upload folder.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to pass the "_id" of the first steps submission to the 2nd step, so that I can perform the update.

How does one go about passing data that I have in my client side controller to my server side controller.

Can I use my view or do I need to call another express route to pass the data?

My project resides at https://github.com/astemborskim/anidopt.git
Currently working out of the temp branch.

Also posting the view, client side and server side controllers in the following gist.

https://gist.github.com/astemborskim/edc5d4a80dfe6e154c99

Comment: Is socketio the best way to try to pass data from client to server? Are there alternatives. Some post I read also mentioned using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way of doing multiple part form.

1. You can use `Bootstrap` and use **[Tagglable Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)**

   - You can always customize it to your liking. Maybe hide or redesign tabs to look like a step. Then have your part one form submit/next button to toggle the second tab
2. Each tab will represent you form part
3. Now, when you submit you first part, you will get the `_id` back
   and can use it for further requests